# How to verify email from Microsoft is legit?

Tags: email, email-signature, security-warning

I recently got an email from "microsoft team" that landed in my outlook junk. This leads to my first question:

1. If this is a legitimate email from "no-reply@microsoft.com", howcome their own emails land in junk folder ***of their own email client?*** Is it not in the interest of Microsoft to make sure their own emails are never marked as junk?

Now this email informed me about someone from India (nowhere close to where I live) logging into my account.

However, this email is not digitally signed- here is my second question:

2. If this is a legitimate Microsoft email why does Microsoft not sign it so their users can be sure it's an authentic email?

Because it is not signed, I don't want to click on the "No it wasn't me" button as I don't know where it leads me. So my final and most important question is:

3. How do I verify this is a legitimate email from Microsoft?

Here is the email:
[image]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/check-the-recent-sign-in-activity-for-your-microsoft-account-5b3cfb8e-70b3-2bd6-9a56-a50177863357 : "If you get an email about unusual activity on your Microsoft account, or if you’re worried that someone else might have used your account, go to the Recent activity page."

Comment: If you don't trust an email (you never should unless you are expecting it) then you should go to the source via a different method. That is exactly why major companies have these kinds of systems in place.

Comment: Do you have a dump of the message headers? Most messages are signed, just not using S/MIME or PGP – they're signed using DKIM, with signature validation done at spam filtering stage.

Comment: Log into your Microsoft account and verify there was online activity from India. Do not click on the link contained in the email. You don’t have to verify if the email is legit. Your email provider has identified it likely wasn’t from Microsoft since it was marked as junk.

Comment: As @user1686 states, *view the full header* to see where the message actually originated.

Comment: Inspect the URL that would be opened if you click "No it wasn't me" (without actually clicking it). Based on the shown URL it should be easier to understand if this is a phishing attempt or legit e-mail.

Comment: Indeed I checked recent activity and there was no login from India. Very interesting to see new phishing tactics!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Mokubai's](https://superuser.com/questions/1718614/how-to-verify-email-from-microsoft-is-legit?noredirect=1#comment2652385_1718614) comment I checked recent activity and indeed there was no login from India.  Always interesting to see new phishing tactics.